# How do I create a like button for a picture?

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-like, gallery

I'm trying to create a like button for a web gallery where underneath each picture a Facebook like button is created. I did get a like button on there at one point, but when the user clicks the like button to share it, it shows a text link to the gallery picture and not a thumbnail of the image. How do I get the like button to show a thumbnail of the gallery image when the user click the like button?

Thanks in advance.